# Cloudera Manager failed to start Activity Monitor

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I downloaded CDH 4.5 quick start vm from [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products.html?productID=F6mO278Rvo). Each service looks good except for below error was seen after I opened Activities tab to view mapreduce activities:

```
The Activity Monitor server (activitymonitor (localhost)) is unavailable or not responding to connections.
```

The problem remains after I tried to restart Activity Monitor service, then I found following error message in the log. Can anybody help take a look?

```
11:24:35.862 PM     WARN    org.mortbay.log     

failed SelectChannelConnector@localhost.localdomain:9999: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

11:24:35.864 PM     WARN    org.mortbay.log     

failed Server@59cc2f42: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

11:24:35.869 PM     ERROR   com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.Main     

Failed to start Firehose
com.cloudera.enterprise.EnterpriseServiceException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.AgentMessageService.startService(AgentMessageService.java:144)
    at com.cloudera.enterprise.EnterpriseService.start(EnterpriseService.java:71)
    at com.cloudera.enterprise.EnterpriseService.start(EnterpriseService.java:68)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.Main.main(Main.java:371)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:315)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.AgentMessageService.startService(AgentMessageService.java:142)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"java.net.BindException: Address already in use" clearly states that port 9999 is already occupied by some other service. You have to check the PID of the service and stop it:

lsof -P | grep LISTEN | grep 9999

use the PID to kill or if you know the service then stop gracefully

Comment: Thanks, it turns out flume was using the same port. After stop flume service, Activity Monitor could be started without any issue.